# PHP getting errors by having an IF statement in an IF statement

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement, syntax-error

## **EDIT:**

My mate pointed out after looking at it for a few hours that it was a wrong bracket

**Problem:**
I am getting constant errors while using this.

**Error:**

`mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /var/www/clients/client**/web***/web/****/data.php on line 101`

**Code:**
Here is a snippet of the code (the rest of the days is not relevant for the code)

```
class Day {
    function getDag($day) {
        $days = array();
        $whatdayisit = date("w");
        if($day == 1) {
            if ($whatdayisit == 1){
            array_push($days, strtotime("Monday"));
            array_push($days, strtotime("Monday + 1 day"));
            }
            else {
            array_push($days, strtotime("next Monday"));
            array_push($days, strtotime("next Monday + 1 day"));
            }
        }
        return $days;
}
```

**Did I do research?**
Yes I did research. I searched for a long time on google and stackoverflow, but I just couldn't find an solution that suited my exact problem.

Comment: Are you missing the } for the end of your function?

Comment: by any chance, did you research `line 101` of your code?

Comment: Which line is line 101? Could you please specify that for us?

Comment: @VolkerK it isn't duplicate. As I stated: "I just couldn't find an solution that suited my exact problem."

Comment: @RyanVincent I AM USING SUBLIME TEXT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing bracket at the end of your function.

```
class Day {
    function getDag($day) {
        $days = array();
        $whatdayisit = date("w");
        if($day == 1) {
            if ($whatdayisit == 1){
            array_push($days, strtotime("Monday"));
            array_push($days, strtotime("Monday + 1 day"));
            }
            else {
            array_push($days, strtotime("next Monday"));
            array_push($days, strtotime("next Monday + 1 day"));
            }
        }
        return $days;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that would trigger that specific error though.

Comment: My mate JUST found it. In the main code on line 110, there was a wrong bracket .... so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing curly brace for your function definition. Try this:

```
class Day {
    function getDag($day) {
        $days = array();
        $whatdayisit = date("w");
        if($day == 1) {
            if ($whatdayisit == 1) {
                array_push($days, strtotime("Monday"));
                array_push($days, strtotime("Monday + 1 day"));
            } else {
                array_push($days, strtotime("next Monday"));
                array_push($days, strtotime("next Monday + 1 day"));
            }
        }
        return $days;
    }
}
```